# Enviar valor de un input con array

Tags: php

Tenemos una aplicaciones con `php` la cual envía imágenes que el usuario elige y le llegan a su correo, el elegir y mandar las imágenes ya no tengo problemas llegan correctamente, pero ahora pidieron agregar un campo de texto para poder agregar notas y ya se muestra el `input` en todas las imágenes pero lo que no llega es el texto que pusieron en el `input`.

Así se ve la interfaz el usuario elige X imágenes y el campo de texto es para enviar la nota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el `input` el SESSION sirve para poner el titulo del `input` ya que la aplicación puede tener imágenes en español o ingles

```
 <input type=\"text\" name=\"repeticion[]\" value    =\"\">".$_SESSION['option2']."
```

Estoy mandando el name del `input` por `POST`

```
 $rp = $_POST["repeticion"];
```

Y agrego la variable en el mensaje

Y aquí es donde hago el envío, si llega el titulo del `input` que es el `SESSION` pero lo que no llega es el valor que ponen en el `input`

```
$_SESSION['msj'] =" ".$_SESSION['option2'].":  ".$rp." Sabemos que no hay nada m&aacutes importante que cuidar de tu salud y recuperarse por completo lo antes posible. ";
```

Este es el `form`

```
if ($_GET){
echo "<form action=\"send.php\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "<div class=\"form-group\" style=\"float:right;\">";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"".$_SESSION['option_1']."\" class=\"btn btn-success\">";

    echo "</div>";

echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
echo "<center>";
    mostrar_imagenes($_SESSION['directorio']."".$_GET["rt"]);    
echo "</center>";
echo "</form>";

}
```

Y tengo la funcion mostrar imagenes, aqui recorre los directorios de las imagenes dependiente de cual categoria eliga y las muestra junto con sus input y checkbox.

```
function mostrar_imagenes($ruta){

    // Se comprueba que realmente sea la ruta de un directorio
    if (is_dir($ruta)){
        // Abre un gestor de directorios para la ruta indicada
        $gestor = opendir($ruta);

        // Recorre todos los archivos del directorio
        while (($archivo = readdir($gestor)) !== false)  {
            // Solo buscamos archivos sin entrar en subdirectorios
            if (is_file($ruta."/".$archivo)) {
               // echo "<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selecciona[]\" value=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."\">&nbsp;".$_SESSION['option']." <br>   <input type=\"text\" name=\"repeticion[]\" value=\"\">".$_SESSION['option2']."    <br>     <input type=\"text\" name=\"series[]\" value=\"\">".$_SESSION['option3']."     <a title=\"Image 1\" href=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."?image=255\" data-toggle=\"lightbox\" data-gallery=\"example-gallery\"><img src=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."\" class=\"thumbnail img-responsive\"  alt=\"".$archivo."\" title=\"".$archivo."\"></a><br></div>";
                echo "<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selecciona[]\" value=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."\">&nbsp;".$_SESSION['option']." <br>   <input type=\"text\" name=\"repeticion[]\" value   =\"\">".$_SESSION['option2']."      <a title=\"Image 1\" href=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."?image=255\" data-toggle=\"lightbox\" data-gallery=\"example-gallery\"><img src=\"".$ruta."/".$archivo."\" class=\"thumbnail img-responsive\"  alt=\"".$archivo."\" title=\"".$archivo."\"></a><br></div>";

            }

        }

        // Cierra el gestor de directorios
        closedir($gestor);
    } else {
        echo "No es una ruta de directorio valida<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Ya lo intente de varias formas pero sigue sin llegar

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con agregándole directamente el valor al input:
Ejemplo:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"repeticion[]\" value=\"".$_SESSION['option2']."\">
```

Espero sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: Lo que me hace eso es poner el titulo del input dentro del input, lo que necesito es que lo que escriban en el input llegue al mensaje

Comment: No veo que tenga error, prueba con quitar el value dentro del input, y quitar los corchetes del name.

Comment: No sigue sin llegar

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo PHP donde recibes los datos del formulario, talvez ahi este el problema.